# What is the difference between putting a static method in a static class and putting an instance method in a static class?

Tags: c#, class, methods, static, static-classes

What is the difference between these two classes?

```
public static class MyClass
{
    public static string SayHello()
    {
        return "Hello";
    }
}

public static class MyClass
{
    public string SayHello()
    {
        return "Hello";
    }
}
```

Is the second SayHello method also static since it is on a static class? If so, is there any reason to include the static keyword on methods when they are defined in a static class?

Comment: The above code will not compile.  You cannot have a non-static method in a static class in C#.

Comment: For future reference, it's very easy to check code snippets like this in LINQPad to see if they compile, and what they will do.

Comment: yes, you should have at least tried the code or did a google search.

Comment: StriplingWarrior Thank you for providing constructive advice for checking out code snippets when I do not have access to Visual Studio.
@Titan2782, I already acknowledged my stupidity on the first answer. You do not need to point it out further. Please be more constructive when posting comments.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The second example is not even possible to do in c#, you will get compile time error:

> 'SayHello': cannot declare instance members in a static class

So you **must** declare members of static calss with `static` keyword.

Comment: Well now I feel dumb. I had not even considered checking if it compiled. haha, thanks for the info!

Answer (score 1):

Static classes cannot be instantiated, so your second piece of code is not compilable. A non-static method can only be accessed in an instantiated class.

Answer (score 0):

> "...Creating a static class is therefore much the same as creating a class that contains only static members and a private constructor. A private constructor prevents the class from being instantiated.
>
> The advantage of using a static class is that the compiler can check to make sure that no instance members are accidentally added. The compiler will guarantee that instances of this class cannot be created."

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/79b3xss3(v=vs.80).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/79b3xss3%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

static classes are sealed, cannot contain instance members. Static methods are a part of the Type not the instance and static methods cannot access instance members. Static methods cannot be virtual but can be overloaded. Static methods also emit 'call' IL opcodes instead of 'callvirt'.

static classes have a static constructor that takes no arguments and it gets called before the first use of the type.